# What font is used in this minecraft logo?

Tags: font-identification

I was on reddit and saw a picture with a font that I liked on it. If anyone can help me identify it, I would appreciate it greatly.

[image]

Comment: Hi Willem, welcome to GDSE and thanks for your question. We have a collection of font identification resources [right here](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/tags/font-identification/info), and it is a good idea to try those first. Please let us know what you have tried without luck. Always good to show a little effort, and chances of getting a good answer increase. Please don't be discouraged, we know that using this site can be a learning curve. We *are* happy to have you!

Comment: I have tried them before I created this and they don't work. I haven't found any tools that help me find what font it is.

Answer (score 1):

Not 100% it, but close enough that it might be the base of a custom in-house font. Found at MyFonts.com, called [Zero](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/fw-identikal/zero/).

[image]

Comment: http://i282.photobucket.com/albums/kk258/nathan_hutchcraft/roy-walker-meme-generator-it-s-good-but-it-s-not-right-1b6cf9.jpg